# Is it possible to pass a character array in weka.core.instance instead of .arff file

Tags: c#, matlab, weka

I am working on a project of facial expression recognition. And i am using weka library in c# to classify features gathered from matlab's `.dll` files (integrated in c# as .Net assembly).

```
weka.core.Instances(new java.io.FileReader("dataset.arff"))
```

is it possible to read array instead of `.arff` file in above code.

Comment: Welcome. Please teach the community how to recreate your problem on their own computers.

Comment: Shaurabh Bharti can you send me a sample code of it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is possible to store the array values to a .arff file.

To create it, you can do following,

```
    string[] lines = { "@ATTRIBUTE sepallength  NUMERIC",
   "@ATTRIBUTE sepalwidth   NUMERIC",
   "@ATTRIBUTE petallength  NUMERIC",
   "@ATTRIBUTE petalwidth   NUMERIC",
   "@ATTRIBUTE class        {Iris-setosa,Iris-versicolor,Iris-virginica}",
   "@DATA"};

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\somefile.arff",
lines);
```

and then for the data part, you can use your array for each line.

```
 string[] dataLines = { "5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa",
   "4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa",
   "4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa",
   "4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa",
   "5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa",
   "5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,Iris-setosa"};

using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = 
                new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\somefile.arff", true))
            {
                foreach (string line in dataLines)
                {
                    file.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
```

[Here](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html) is some guide for .arff file provided by waikato for Weka.